# How to pass toString from child to parent using super.toString() in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, tostring

Working on a Java project to study Polymorphism. I am trying to learn how to pass a toString() up the line from the bottom child. I have to pass the toString form Hardware.java to Tool.java to ScrewDriver.java and then in Player.java, I need to print out an array that I have defined.

Here is the files:

```
public class Player {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Hardware> hardware = new ArrayList<>();
        ScrewDriver screwdriver1 = new ScrewDriver("Flathead", "Use this to open paint cans", 150, "Woodworking", true, 15, 10);

        hardware.add(screwdriver1);

        for(Hardware tool : hardware)
            System.out.print(tool);
    }
}

public class Hardware {
    private String name;
    private String message;
    private int points;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        return "Name: " + name + " Message: " + message + " Points: " + points;
    }
}

public class Tool extends Hardware {
    private String type;
    private boolean isDangerous;
    private int percentDangerous;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        return "Type: " + type + " Message: " + isDangerous + " Percent Dangerous: " + percentDangerous;
    }
}

public class ScrewDriver extends Tool {
    private double length;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        return "Length: " + length;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the only thing that prints from the array is the Length.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the desired result to have the `Name` `Message` and `Points` print out as well with the `Length`?

Comment: Hey Joshua - When you post code for people to look at, please try to 1) format it properly, and 2) remove the parts that are not relevant to your question.  You posted > 200 lines, but the part of the code that is actually relevant to your question is 10 to 20 lines max.  (And lots of blank lines really doesn't make your code more readable.  Put yourself in the place of someone trying to read it in a web browser.   Hey ... just try it yourself!)

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone! Sorry about the spelling errors, formatting and to much information. Once I took away the super.toString() from Hardware and added super.toString() to the return in the Tool and ScrewDriver class, everything seemed to work! Thank you very much. I understand what I was doing wrong now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access a subclass's methods from a superclass. It is only possible the other way around. So you can access Hardware's toString() in Tool class and Tool's toString() in ScrewDriver class.

In order to print toString() information of all the superclasses of ScrewDriver in ScrewDriver's toString() method, you need to modify all the toString() methods in this inheritance chain.

Suppose that Hardware's toString() is like this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + name + " Message: " + message + " Points: " + points;
}
```

You need to modify Tool's toString() to following, so that it uses its superclass's toString() method:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + " Type: " + type + " Message: " + isDangerous + " Percent Dangerous: " + percentDangerous;
}
```

And finally, ScrewDriver's toString() should invoke its superclass's toString() method as following:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{    
    return super.toString() + " Length: " + length;
}
```

Only then ScrewDriver's toString() will print the information of all its superclasses.

Comment: `return String.format("%s Type: %s Message: %s Percent Dangerous: %s", super.toString(), type, isDangerous, percentDangerous)` is more readable than multiple (more that 5) stirng concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
super.toString();
```

method call is returning String, but you are not using result of this call, so basically you are wasting CPU cycles on it.

A possible solution would be something like:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + "\nLength: " + length;
}
```